# $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} {\frac{24n-8}{n^2+n+1}} \ne 0.5$

Tags: calculus, limits

Got stuck in disproving limit, hope you can help/hint me. Disprove $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} {\frac{24n-8}{n^2+n+1}} \ne 0.5$$

My effort :
So I did common factor and got to $\left|{\frac {-n^2+47n-17}{2n^2+2n+2}}\right|$

Now I don't know how to proceed.
I tried to do something and got to  $\left|{\frac {n^2-47n+17}{2n^2+2n+2}}\right|$ but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\dfrac{24n-8}{n^2+n+1}=\dfrac{n(24-\frac{8}{n})}{n(n+1+\frac{1}{n})}=\dfrac{24-\frac{8}{n}}{n+1+\frac{1}{n}}$

So $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{24n-8}{n^2+n+1}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{24-\frac{8}{n}}{n+1+\frac{1}{n}}=0$,

since $24-\dfrac{8}{n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}24$ and $n+1+\dfrac{1}{n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}+\infty$

Answer (score 2):

Analysis flavored answer: Choose $\varepsilon<\dfrac{5}{362},$ then for all $n>48$ we have $\left| \dfrac{24n-8}{n^2+n+1}-\dfrac{1}{2}\right|>\varepsilon,$ and therefore the limit cannot be $\dfrac{1}{2}.$

> This epsilon works because  $\dfrac{5}{362}=\left(\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{88}{181}\right)$, where $\frac{88}{181}$ is just the result of setting $n=48$ into the sequence term, this is less than $\frac{1}{2},$ and the sequence is monotonically decreasing, so the limit cannot be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I know that after $n>48$... I'm trying to find $ε=$something such that for any $n>N_0$ the expression is $>=ε$. That's why I'm stuck , I don't know how to do absolute value and proceed

Comment: I gave you a choice of $\varepsilon$ in my answer :)